# Cannot load data.json file using jQuery and React.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, reactjs

I must say first that I come from mobile development. I am very new with web development so this is probably an amateur questions.

I am building a react.js project using create-react-app (which uses Babel). I am trying to follow a tutorial where I am supposed to import a *.json file when my component mounts. I can't seem to be able to access my data, and I get an error saying "filteredApts.map is not a function".

Here are my imports:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Here is my componentWillMount method:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log($.get('./data.json', function(){}.bind(this))) //This seems to get an HTML Page returned!
    this.serverRequest = $.get('./data.json', function(result) {
      var tempApts = result;
      this.setState({
        myAppointments: tempApts
      }); //setState
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

my render method:

```
render: function() {

var filteredApts = this.state.myAppointments;
filteredApts = filteredApts.map(function(item, index) {
  return (<li className="pet-item media" key={index}>
            <div className="pet-info media-body">
              <div className="pet-head">
                <span className="pet-name">{this.state.myAppointments[index].petName}</span>
                <span className="apt-date pull right">{this.state.myAppointments[index].petName}</span>
              </div>
              <div className="owner-name"><span className="label-item">Owner:</span>
              {this.state.myAppointments[index].ownerName}</div>
              <div className="apt-notes">
              {this.state.myAppointments[index].aptNotes}</div>
            </div>
          </li>)
}.bind(this));
return (<div className="interface">
          <div className="item-list media-list">
           <ul className="item-list media-list"></ul>
              </div>
            </div>)
  } //render
}); //MainInterface
```

Here is my map of files:

[image]

And finally my console log:

[image]

Is somebody capable of pointing out what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to change this line:

```
var filteredApts = this.state.myAppointments;
```

to this

```
var filteredApts = this.state.myAppointments || [];
```

You use asynchronous data fetching and at the moment of rendering it can be no myAppointments yet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Looks like your responseText is html.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

First, './data.json' was pointing to the public folder by default.

Second, I was missing {filteredApts} in

```
return (<div className="interface">
               <ul className="item-list media-list">{filteredApts}</ul>
            </div>)
```

Thanks anyways to all.